# Group search results by category

Tags: categories, pages, search, search-engines

For a client I need to group results on the search results page by category. In this case it would *not* be posts, but **pages** that have inherited categories form posts with the [Add Tags And Category To Page And Post Types](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/add-tags-and-category-to-page/) plugin.

This is the non-edited search results page template:

```
    <div id="content">

    <div id="inner-content" class="wrap cf">

        <main id="main" class="m-all t-2of3 d-5of7 cf" role="main">
            <h1 class="archive-title"><span><?php _e( 'Search Results for:', 'bonestheme' ); ?></span> <?php echo esc_attr(get_search_query()); ?></h1>

            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('cf'); ?> role="article">

                    <header class="entry-header article-header">

                        <h3 class="search-title entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

                            <p class="byline entry-meta vcard">
                                    <?php printf( __( 'Posted %1$s by %2$s', 'bonestheme' ),
                                    /* the time the post was published */
                                    '<time class="updated entry-time" datetime="' . get_the_time('Y-m-d') . '" itemprop="datePublished">' . get_the_time(get_option('date_format')) . '</time>',
                                        /* the author of the post */
                                        '<span class="by">by</span> <span class="entry-author author" itemprop="author" itemscope itemptype="http://schema.org/Person">' . get_the_author_link( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) . '</span>'
                                    ); ?>
                            </p>

                    </header>

                    <section class="entry-content">
                            <?php the_excerpt( '<span class="read-more">' . __( 'Read more &raquo;', 'bonestheme' ) . '</span>' ); ?>

                    </section>

                    <footer class="article-footer">

                        <?php if(get_the_category_list(', ') != ''): ?>
                        <?php printf( __( 'Filed under: %1$s', 'bonestheme' ), get_the_category_list(', ') ); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php the_tags( '<p class="tags"><span class="tags-title">' . __( 'Tags:', 'bonestheme' ) . '</span> ', ', ', '</p>' ); ?>

                    </footer> <!-- end article footer -->

                </article>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php boilerplate_page_navi(); ?>

                <?php else : ?>

                        <article id="post-not-found" class="hentry cf">
                            <header class="article-header">
                                <h1><?php _e( 'Sorry, No Results.', 'bonestheme' ); ?></h1>
                            </header>
                            <section class="entry-content">
                                <p><?php _e( 'Try your search again.', 'bonestheme' ); ?></p>
                            </section>
                            <footer class="article-footer">
                                    <p><?php _e( 'This is the error message in the search.php template.', 'bonestheme' ); ?></p>
                            </footer>
                        </article>

                <?php endif; ?>

            </main>

                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

        </div>

</div>
```

And this is how I got so far with a little help:

```
<div id="content">

<div id="inner-content" class="wrap cf">

    <main id="main" class="m-all t-2of3 d-5of7 cf" role="main">

        <h1 class="archive-title"><span><?php _e( 'Search Results for:', 'boilerplate' ); ?></span> <?php echo esc_attr(get_search_query()); ?></h1>


    <?php
      $list_per_category = [];

      $search_filters = array(
        'post_type' => 'page' // Doorzoekt alle post types
      );

      $search_result = new WP_Query( $search_filters );

    //var_dump($search_result);

      if ($search_result->have_posts()) : while ($search_result->have_posts()) : $search_result->the_post();

        //Genereer de html voor het zoekresultaat van de post, en bewaar deze in een buffer
        ob_start(); ?>

          <article>

            <?php // create our link now that the post is setup ?>
              <h4 class="search-title entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>

            <?php the_excerpt( '<span class="read-more">' . __( 'Read more &raquo;', 'boilerplate' ) . '</span>' ); ?>
          </article>
          <?php

          $post_html = ob_get_clean();

        //Loop de hoofdcategorieen van de post door en maak hier een overkoepelende structuur voor aan die we kunnen gebruiken voor de lijstweergave van het zoekresultaat.
        $post_categories = get_the_category();
        foreach ($post_categories as $post_category) :
          if($post_category->parent == 0):

            if (!isset($list_per_category[$post_category->term_id])):
              $list_per_category[$post_category->term_id]['category'] = $post_category;
              $list_per_category[$post_category->term_id]['posts'] = [];
            endif;

            $list_per_category[$post_category->term_id]['posts'][] = $post_html;

          endif;
        endforeach;

      endwhile;


      //Doorloop de gemaakte structuur van posts per category en toon deze
      foreach ($list_per_category as $list_item) :

        echo '<div class="category' . $list_item['category']->slug . '">
            <h2>' . $list_item['category']->name . '</h2>';

        foreach ($list_item['posts'] as $post_html) :
          echo $post_html;
        endforeach;

        echo '</div>';
      endforeach;


      else : ?>

          <article id="post-not-found" class="hentry cf">
              <header class="article-header">
                  <h1><?php _e( 'Sorry, No Results.', 'bonestheme' ); ?></h1>
              </header>
              <section class="entry-content">
                  <p><?php _e( 'Try your search again.', 'bonestheme' ); ?></p>
              </section>
              <footer class="article-footer">
                  <p><?php _e( 'This is the error message in the search.php template.', 'bonestheme' ); ?></p>
              </footer>
          </article>

      <?php endif; ?>

    </main>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

</div>
```

The problem here is that all pages are being listed that have a category, not just the search results that have a category. It looks like the loop is missing some kind of search-query parameter. I would like to know how I can improve the page template so it shows the search results by category. Maybe there is a much easier way than what I posted above?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Add in the [search parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter) to your query:

```
$search_filters = array(
   'post_type' => 'page', // Doorzoekt alle post types
   's' => $keyword // show only posts that meet the current search query
);
```

And above that you should just be able to grab the keyword right from your querystring like so:

```
$keyword = $_GET['s'];
```

There's also a WordPress [native function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_search_query) that grabs your current search query which might be better to use than grabbing it manually from the querystring:

```
$keyword = get_search_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it does not solve my problem yet. When I search for something that I am sure of is on the site, I simply get nothing. When there are no search results, the 'No results' message shows up as expected.

I just can't imagine that I am the only one with this question, but there is so little to find about it.

This is my code now:
`

```
    <div id="inner-content" class="wrap cf">

        <main id="main" class="m-all t-2of3 d-5of7 cf" role="main">
            <h1 class="archive-title"><span><?php _e( 'Search Results for:', 'boilerplate' ); ?></span> <?php echo esc_attr(get_search_query()); ?></h1>

            <?php
                $keyword = $_GET['s'];
                $list_per_category = [];

                $search_filters = array(
                   'post_type' => 'page', // Doorzoekt alle post types
                   's' => $keyword // show only posts that meet the current search query
                );

                $search_result = new WP_Query( $search_filters );

                //var_dump($search_result);
            ?>

            <?php if ($search_result->have_posts()) : while ($search_result->have_posts()) : $search_result->the_post();

        //Genereer de html voor het zoekresultaat van de post, en bewaar deze in een buffer
        ob_start(); ?>

        <article>

            <?php // create our link now that the post is setup ?>
                  <h4 class="search-title entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>

            <?php the_excerpt( '<span class="read-more">' . __( 'Read more &raquo;', 'boilerplate' ) . '</span>' ); ?>
        </article>
        <?php

        $post_html = ob_get_clean();

        //Loop de hoofdcategorieen van de post door en maak hier een overkoepelende structuur voor aan die we kunnen gebruiken voor de lijstweergave van het zoekresultaat.
        $post_categories = get_the_category();

        foreach ($post_categories as $post_category) :

          if($post_category->parent == 0):

            if (!isset($list_per_category[$post_category->term_id])):
              $list_per_category[$post_category->term_id]['category'] = $post_category;
              $list_per_category[$post_category->term_id]['posts'] = [];
            endif;

            $list_per_category[$post_category->term_id]['posts'][] = $post_html;

          endif;

        endforeach;

      endwhile; 

      //Doorloop de gemaakte structuur van posts per category en toon deze
      foreach ($list_per_category as $list_item) :

        echo '<div class="category' . $list_item['category']->slug . '">
            <h2>' . $list_item['category']->name . '</h2>';

        foreach ($list_item['posts'] as $post_html) :
          echo $post_html;
        endforeach;

        echo '</div>';

      endforeach;

      else : ?>

        <article id="post-not-found" class="hentry cf">
            <header class="article-header">
                <h1><?php _e( 'Sorry, No Results.', 'boilerplate' ); ?></h1>
            </header>
            <section class="entry-content">
                <p><?php _e( 'Try your search again.', 'boilerplate' ); ?></p>
            </section>
            <footer class="article-footer">
                    <p><?php _e( 'This is the error message in the search.php template.', 'boilerplate' ); ?></p>
            </footer>
        </article>

    <?php endif; ?>

        </main>

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    </div>

</div>
```